# Vuex not returning submodule's getters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, vuex-modules, vuex4

I have a following store structure:
[image]

In order to access the `orders` getter (here `Array[0]`) I used: `store.getters['pages/my/orders/orders']` and it worked  on Nuxt 2 (Vue 2).

After refactoring to Vue 3 (Vuex 4) I can only get getters from shallowly nested modules, i.e:

```
store.getters['auth/isLoggedIn'] // works, returns the getter
store.getters['pages/my/orders/orders'] // is undefined despite being shown in Vue DevTools
```

In fact `store.getters` doesn't have any `pages` getters, it only returns root getters, or module getters (but not submodules).

Edit: Sometimes it takes writing it down to notice the issue. `pages/my/orders/orders` is indeed technically not a getter, but a part of the state. But how come then `store.getters['pages/my/orders/orders']` worked on Nuxt?

Edit 2: actually we do have `orders` getter inside `pages/my/orders` as well, I don't know why Vue DevTools is not showing it :/

Comment: Not an answer to your question but Pinia is the recommended Vue 3 store plugin and is maintained by the Vue core team, it is basically Vuex 5.  The level of support would be better if you upgraded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `namespaced: true` needs to be in every single module that has submodules. Without it submodule getters are not taken into account. It's very easy to overlook as there is no warning or error.

So in my case to be able to access `store.getters['pages/my/orders/orders']` I had to add to `pages`, `my`, `orders` modules:

```
export default {
  namespaced: true, // this was missing
  modules: {
    ...submodules
  }
```